# How to avoid horizontal scroll in tables in HTML?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This might seem quite easy or dummy question but as a beginner to HTML/Bootsrap/CSS, it's important to me.

My problem is that no matter what I do I get horizontal scrolling on small displays. Finally I thought maybe I should shrink the font size on small displays. But I don't know how to set different style just for xs size?

There is this table:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    @Html.Partial("_Property/Grid/TableHeader") 
    @Html.Partial("_Property/Grid/SponsoredRows",Model.SearchResult.SponsoredResult)
...
<tr data-link-url="@Url.Action(" ....
</tr>
```

tr s are pretty much like this:

```
<tr class="warning" data-link-url="@Url.Action("Click", "Impression", new {id = listing.SponsoredEntityImpression.ID, guid = listing.SponsoredEntityImpression.GUID, area = AreaNames.Ad})">
        @Html.Partial("_Property/Grid/RowCells", listing.PropertyListingSummary)
    </tr>
```

And here are td s in a row:

```
    <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@Html.Partial("_Property/Grid/RowIcons", Model)</td>
<td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@Model.Code</td>
<td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@Html.Partial("_Property/Grid/RowPhoto", Model)</td>

<td class="test">@propertyPresentationHelper.BuildRegion(Model)</td>
<td>@propertyPresentationHelper.BuildTitle(Model)</td>
<td>@propertyPresentationHelper.BuildArea(Model)</td>
<td>@propertyPresentationHelper.BuildPriceAndPricePerArea(Model)</td>


<style>
    p {
        color: red;
    }

    .test {
        font-size: 8px;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries: [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
   /* Here dimension for xs */
}
```